# Having Issue on Redirecting With Session in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, header

I am trying to create a simple login system in WordPress using core PHP but I am getting this error message

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> (output started at
> /www/www/www/wp-content/themes/mytheme/header.php:20)
> in
> /www/www/www/wp-content/themes/mytheme/page-solutions.php
> on line 9

In the `header.php` template I have

```
<?php
session_start();
/**
 * The header.
 *
 */
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
```

and in the `page-solutions.php` page

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Solutions
 *
 */
get_header();

if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
header("location: home");
exit;
}
```

As you can see I am trying to redirect not logged users to `front-page.php` which I called it Home but I am getting error on `header("location: home");` Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions that modifies headers must be called before any output is made. In this case you're calling get_header() functions which sends an output, and then youre trying to modify the header. Try changing the order that you execute the code, like this:

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Solutions
*
*/

 if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
 header("location: home");
 exit;
 }

 get_header();
```

Comment: Thanks Jairo but as you can see the `session_start();` is claimed in hearer template wouldn't this make conflict?!

Comment: Hey @Suffii I suppose that the session is created on the login page, right? if so, you won't have any problem. If there's a session the solution template will render correctly, if not will redirect to home.